# installing 3rd party JARs

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-2, maven-3

I have a maven project in Eclipse called TdkUtils, with this pom.xml:
This is a utils project. So I want to create a jar, put it in the repository and use it in another projects.

```
...
<groupId>com.tdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>tdkUtils</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>tdkUtils</name>
...
```

But I got these errors when installing the plugin:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:tdkUtils nunito$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=target/tdkUtils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tdkUtils 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ tdkUtils ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.353 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-18T11:29:58+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project tdkUtils: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR] [0]  'groupId' is missing.
[ERROR] [1]  'artifactId' is missing.
[ERROR] [2]  'packaging' is missing.
[ERROR] [3]  'version' is missing.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: are you sure that syntax of your pom.xml right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just execute `mvn install` while inside the same directory with the util `pom.xml` file, maven will install the jar file into local repository for the user.

After that, the jar file can be used by the same user from other projects.

Answer (score 0):

you can install a jar to local repo without pom.xml like this:
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=target/tdkUtils-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.tdk -DartifactId=tdkUtils -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar`